# How to move vertices without duplicating them?

Tags: modeling, vertices

Whenever I move vertices using **grab function** (<kbd>G</kbd>), the original vertices always stay in their position. How can I prevent this?

Comment: There probably are duplicate vertices in the same place as the ones you have selected. Press `Space` and type "Remove Doubles", then press `Enter`. See if that works

Comment: It should be noted that using *G* (grab/move) DOES NOT/CANNOT generate duplicated vertices. Those vertices where created using a different tool.

Answer (score 8):

This may be because you have a couple duplicate vertices in the same location.

Select all your vertices using <kbd>A</kbd> in edit mode and then press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring a dropdown menu. Either select "*Remove Doubles*" or press <kbd>R</kbd> as it's faster. Now try moving your vertex. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have duplicate vertices in the same location of the ones you have selected and want to move. There's not really any use for such a condition, so there is a simple operator capable of fixing this: *Remove Doubles*.

Enter *Edit mode* and press <kbd>Space</kbd>; then type "Remove Doubles" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: {Ctrl}+{V} > remove doubles.

Answer (score 3):

Did you do any extrude operations and cancel them with Esc prior to doing the translate?  This is an error I made early on, not realizing that Extrude was a macro and hitting Esc cancels the grab of the duplicate vertices rather than the duplication of the vertices.  So for example, if you hit E to extrude, hit Esc to cancel, then hit G to translate, you'll be translating a duplicate set of vertices.